# Running a check within a SQL query (Maybe a subquery?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple laptop testing booking system with 6 laptops, named Laptop01 to 06 that each have three allocated time slots.

A user is is able to select these time slots if the slot is not booked or if the booking has been cancelled/declined.

While I have working code, I've realised a fatal error that causes a cancelled/declined slot to duplicate.

Let me explain...

[image: Database Design]

- `event_information` - Holds the booking event information (only ID is
  needed for this example)
- `event_machine_time` - This hold all the
  laptops, with three rows per laptop with the unique timings available
  to choose from
- `event_booking` - This holds the actual booking, which
  then links to another candidate database, not included here

I then run a simple query that joins everything together and (I thought) identifies the booked events:

```
SELECT machine_laptop, machine_name, B.id AS m_id, C.id AS c_id, C.confirmed AS c_confirmed, C.live AS c_live, 
(C.id IS NOT NULL AND C.confirmed !=2 AND C.live !=0) AS booked
FROM event_information A
INNER JOIN event_machine_time B ON ( 1 =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN event_booking C on (B.id = C.machine_time_id and A.id = C.information_id )
WHERE A.id = :id
ORDER BY `B`.`id` DESC
```

`booked` is checking if `confirmed` isn't 2 - which means the booking has been cancelled/declined (0 - not confirmed, 1 - confirmed) and `live` is checking for deletion (0 - deleted, 1 - not deleted).

However if a person either gets deleted (`live` - 0) or cancels/declines (`confirmed` - 2) then in my front end slot selector dropdown it will add an extra slot as the `booked` column is still 0, as shown below:

[image]

This allows the user to then choose from two slots at the same time, meaning double bookings occur.

I now know that using a Join is the wrong thing to do, and I'm presuming that I need to run a subquery, but I'm not an SQL expert and I would love some help to find examples of similar 'second queries' that I can learn from.

Also apologies if my terminology is wrong.

**EDIT:**

As requested I've included the output:

[image]

**Second edit and conclusion:**

In the end I managed to craft a solution together using a sub query to remove the cancelled/declined bookings before the output, then use a Group By to only display one of each timing. This most likely isn't the best way, but it worked for me.

```
SELECT machine_laptop, machine_name, B.id AS m_id, C.id AS c_id, C.confirmed AS c_confirmed, C.live AS c_live, B.start_time AS b_start_time, (
            C.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND C.confirmed !=2
            AND C.live !=0
            ) AS booked
            FROM event_information A
            INNER JOIN event_machine_time B ON (1=1) 
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM event_booking WHERE confirmed <> '2' AND live <> '0') AS C ON ( B.id = C.machine_time_id AND A.id = C.information_id ) 
            WHERE A.id = :id
            GROUP BY m_id
            ORDER BY machine_name ASC, b_start_time ASC
```

Thank you for all your input.

Comment: Sample data added as text to the question would be useful.

Comment: I am unclear what the issue is.  You seem to be inserting something somewhere along the way -- and that is your problem.  But I can't figure out if this is happening on a delete or by the UI or somewhere else.  The problem is the insert, and a simple unique constraint will probably fix your problem.

Comment: Just a little remark: Your subquery is comparing numbers against strings while the main query is comparing clearly numeric column values against numbers, which is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
SELECT machine_laptop, machine_name, B.id AS m_id, C.id AS c_id, C.confirmed 
AS c_confirmed, C.live AS c_live, 
(C.id IS NOT NULL AND C.confirmed !=2 AND C.live !=0) AS booked
FROM event_information A
LEFT JOIN event_booking C ON A.id = C.information_id
RIGHT JOIN event_machine_time B ON B.id = C.machine_time_id
WHERE A.id = :id
ORDER BY `B`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Hi, there's a C missing on event_booking, but a RIGHT JOIN only returns the 4 bookings on Laptop 6 and still counts the two as booked = 0. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: would you please put your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the event_booking (B) as starting point for your query, you can see that there's no need to use pull all rows and columns from A and C. Intead you can join on matching rows directly. But as I can't even properly grasp what your query is trying to achieve, I have couple of questions first:

While this may work it's actually something that's not under your control nor defined by you. Some more strict mode would politely tell you to specify which aliased table you're referring to in your SELECT, as this

```
SELECT machine_laptop, machine_name  -- combined with
FROM event_information A
```

actually doesn't make sense and the only reason why it's working is that you're leveraging on MySQL's optimisations. In addition to that you're trying to do table joins in a mixed mode (meaning that you use both JOIN and WHERE tA.colX=tB.colY methods. This makes it really difficult to follow.

```
INNER JOIN event_machine_time B ON ( 1 =1 )
```

Um? What exactly is the e purpose of this? As far as I can tell this will only cause it to JOIN both full tables, only to later filter the result using WHERE.

Furthermore, are you even using primary keys? Your condition includes **C.id IS NOT NULL** while primary keys can't even contain NULLs (as NULL is third boolean state in SQL land. There is True, False, and Null (meaning Undefined, which obviously couldn't be used in primary key, as primary key must be unique and Undefined value can be anything or nothing - ergo it's violating the uniqueness requirement). So I'm assuming you're actually using this NULL check because the temp table during JOIN seems to contain them?

EDIT: 
Try to split this into two parts, where you first join 2 tables, and then join third table with the result.

I suggest you go briefly over [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) - as this is pretty great post and clarifies many aspects.

For startest I'd go with something like:

```
SELECT
    <i.cols>,
    <b.cols>,
    <mt.cols>, 
    IF(b.confirmed !=2 AND b.live !=0, True, False) sa booked
FROM 
   event_booking b 
LEFT JOIN 
   event_information i ON b.information_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN 
   event_machine_time mt ON b.machine_time_id = mt.id
WHERE <conditions>
```

Later I'd change LEFT JOIN into something more appropriate. However bear in mind that INNER JOIN is only useful if you're 100% sure that there rows returned from joined table columns are unique.

Can there even be 1:n, n:1 relationship between i and b tables? I'd assume there couldn't  be multiple bookings to same event info (n:1), nor there'd be so that event information is the same for multiple events ? (1:n)

Comment: I've include above what I would like to achieve (including the current duplicate error). I don't see how I can build my query based on event_booking as I'm trying to output all the available time slots from event_machine_time then check if they are booked against the event_booking table. I will try to clean up my query. Thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: Ok. In response to your "I now know that using a Join is the wrong thing to do, and I'm presuming that I need to run a subquery" 

Actually it's quite the other way around. If possible everything should be joined using JOINs, as a preferred method. It's just more optimal and performs better. The question is how you're starting your join.... 
I'm going to edit my response now...

Comment: Thank you for your help, however this causes the query to only output the booked slots and not the available ones. I've added a rough solution above, which I'll clean up later in my actual code as the `booking` result is now redundant

Comment: Well, your question didn't reveal the fact that you have these slot placeholders in database (although I'd rather generate calendar on the UI side and fill only existing data from database). Your column names surely don't hint on this. Otherwise I would've included them as starting point.
No worries, though :)